# Velocity-Tools in Spring 3 app - Linktool causes NPE, how to solve?

Tags: apache, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, velocity

I'm using a modified VelocityToolboxView (found somwhere here on stackoverflow) to make use of the Velocity-Tools 2.0 in spring 3. 
It looks like it is configuring well, but when I call the $link tool in a .vm file I get an NPE. Scanning through the Velocity-Tools sources I found that it tries to configure the tool with request and response from the ValueParser props, but they are null here.

Here the stack:

```
LinkTool.configure(ValueParser) line: 100   
LinkTool(SafeConfig).configure(Map) line: 113   
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
ToolInfo.invoke(Method, Object, Object) line: 363   
ToolInfo.configure(Object, Map<String,Object>) line: 294    
ToolInfo.create(Map<String,Object>) line: 255   
Toolbox.getFromInfo(String, String, Map<String,Object>) line: 152   
Toolbox.get(String, String, Map<String,Object>) line: 112   
ToolContext.findTool(String) line: 221  
ToolContext.get(String) line: 206   
VelocityContext(AbstractContext).get(String) line: 197
```

When the ValueParser needs to have the request/response values in its map at this time, where is this normally injected and by whom?

Here is the view class I use:

```
public class VelocityToolsView extends VelocityToolboxView
{

  private static ToolContext toolContext;

  @Override
  protected Context createVelocityContext(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map model,
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
  {
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext(getToolContext());
    if (model != null)
    {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entrySet = model.entrySet();
      for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : entrySet)
      {
        context.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      }
    }
    return context;
  }

  private ToolContext getToolContext() throws IllegalStateException, IOException
  {
    if (toolContext == null)
    {
      XmlFactoryConfiguration factoryConfiguration = new XmlFactoryConfiguration("Default Tools");
      factoryConfiguration.read(getServletContext()
          .getResourceAsStream(getToolboxConfigLocation()));
      ToolManager toolManager = new ToolManager();
      toolManager.configure(factoryConfiguration);
      toolContext = toolManager.createContext();
    }
    return toolContext;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VelocityToolbox is something from ancient times that was deprecated 5 years ago. I am using [this technique](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-integrate-velocity-tools-2-0-with-spring/) to integrate Tools into Spring.

Comment: But I derived my class from the template class on your page. If you compare the code it is almost doing the same, just with lazy loading of the static field. The problem is still that the LinkTool fails to work because it expects the request and response in the toolProps when ToolContext tries to configure the $link tool (Line 84-103 of org.apache.velocity.tools.view.LinkTool.java )

Comment: @Kai It's not the same. I see word `Toolbox` in your code which means you are using wrong method. You shouldn't be using anything toolbox-related.

Comment: @Kai Maybe try the exact code from the example and see if it works first, then you can start changing it to you liking. I have tools configured as I showed and Link tool works without problems.

Comment: the only difference between your and mine version is that I'm getting the toolcontext configuration using the servlet resource loader now. Your static version isn't able to find it in WEB-INF/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was finding this problem too and eventually solved it using [this](https://gist.github.com/4549746) variation on @serg's technique.